# Pandas dataframe with column of type set: How to initialize and update values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, set

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe with existing content:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['content'])
df['content'] = pd.Series(["a","b","c","d","e"])
df.head()
```

```
    content
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
```

1. How can add a column with empty sets?
2. How can I update a subset of records´ sets (e.g. `set.add(value)`)

Answer (score 1):

Both questions turn out more difficult than expected.

To initialize a new column with empty sets:

```py
df['Sets'] = [set() for _ in range(len(df))]
df.head()
```

```
content Sets
0   a   {}
1   b   {}
2   c   {}
3   d   {}
4   e   {}
```

To update a a subset of records´ sets with a unique string:

```py
row_ids_to_update = [1,3,4]
column_id_set = df.columns.get_loc("Sets")
update_string = "uid12345"
df.iloc[row_ids_to_update, column_id_set].apply(
    lambda x: x.add(update_string))
df.head()
```

```
content Sets
0   a   {}
1   b   {uid12345}
2   c   {}
3   d   {uid12345}
4   e   {uid12345}
```

Perhaps there's a faster way for large quantities of updates, e.g. avoiding **lambda**?